# Intel 8080 Read/Set Interrupt Mask Instructions

Tags: assembly, intel, 8080, 8085, intel-8080

According to Intel's *8080-8085 Assembly Language Programming* guide, the OP Code `20` corresponds to the Read Interrupt Mask (RIM) instruction, and `30` corresponds to the Set Interrupt Mask (SIM) instruction.

[image: RIM]
[image: SIM]

[image: Instruction Set Guide]

But these interrupts were only available on the 8085. What did these instructions do on the earlier 8080 chipset? How do they work on the 8085?

Comment: Thanks for the new tags @mnem!  I'm just one rep away from being able to create my own as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 8085 added two new instruction functions: SIM and RIM.

These instructions differ from the 8080 instructions in that each has multiple functions.  The SIM instruction sets the interrupt mask and optionally writes one bit of data to the serial interface.  The RIM instruction reads one bit from the serial interface (if one is present) and the interrupt mask into register A, the accumulator.

There are also differences with regard to signal processing signal processing.  The new RST5.5, RST6.5, and RST7.5 hardware interrupts take priority over the Interrupt line at pin 14, the only interrupt on the 8080.

These instructions are NOPs on the 8080.

Comment: The biggest advantage to the SIM and RIM is they are **fast**.  They execute in 4 clock cycles, so you can sample SID and/or toggle SOD considerably faster than any I/O or memory-mapped port.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your specific question, the 0x20 and 0x30 opcodes on the 8080 were undefined.  In practice they were equivalent to NOP (0x00).

A handy table of 8080 instructions can be found here:
http://pastraiser.com/cpu/i8080/i8080_opcodes.html

Comment: How dumb of me to not include that in my self-answer.  Thanks.  (Already hit my vote limit for the day but I will come back in 2 hours to give this answer some love).